# Numeric node property is rounded when querying with Cypher

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am running the following query using Cypher on Neo4j 2.0.1

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.value = -4810333952080461631 OR n.value = -163182636343344959 
RETURN n.value
```

Results:

```
-4810333952080462000
-163182636343344960
```

It seems that the values are getting rounded. I tried it through their web ui, and the node js neo4j client.

When I browse to the node through their web ui, I can see that it holds the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was opened in an issue: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2009. The JSON returned is correct. If it's not correct coming from the client you're using (you don't mention which), there is possibly a bug in the client, where a value is converted to a double and losing precision.